# Add filteres to my query cause error. Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this query that works fine. It brings data from two tables, manager_details and users. What I need is to bring the sum of managers score **BUT from week 1 to week 7**. Week is another field in manager_details table which could have values from 0-x.

```
SELECT
  SUM(mng.score) AS accumulated_score,
  mng.manager_id AS manager_id,
  users.id,
  users.fname,
  users.lname
FROM manager_details AS mng
  JOIN users
    ON users.id = mng.manager_id
GROUP BY manager_id
ORDER BY accumulated_score DESC
LIMIT 5
```

In order to get score from week 1 to week 7, I have tried to add

```
SELECT
  SUM(mng.score) AS accumulated_score,
  mng.manager_id AS manager_id,
  users.id,
  users.fname,
  users.lname
FROM manager_details AS mng
WHERE  mng.week >= 1 AND mng.week <= 6    -- this line
  JOIN users
    ON users.id = mng.manager_id
GROUP BY manager_id
ORDER BY accumulated_score DESC
LIMIT 5
```

and got this

> Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'join users
>       on users.id = mng.manager_id GROUP BY manager_id

and also tried

```
     ...         
     HAVING mng.week >= 1 AND mng.week <= 6  -- <-- 
     ...
```

I also put the HAVING clase after GROUP BY, before GROUP BY, at the end and did not work, got mysql error check syntax..etc.

I am doing something wrong, but not sure what is it.

So, What clause to use and where do I put that condition to filter my mng.score and get only scores that lie between weeks 1-7?

Comment: `WHERE  mng.week >= 1 AND mng.week <= 6` - is ok. You better put your modified query and the exact error message. "I am doing something wrong, but not sure what is it." --- and how are we supposed to help if you don't show it to us?

Comment: totally slipped my mind to add the code error, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: `WHERE` goes **after** `JOIN` and **before** `GROUP BY`

Comment: You need to join before `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You can change `JOIN` to `FROM manager_details AS mng, users` and put `users.id = mng.manager_id` inside `WHERE`

Comment: yup, the order i used was wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  SUM(mng.score) AS accumulated_score,
  mng.manager_id AS manager_id,
  users.id,
  users.fname,
  users.lname
FROM manager_details AS mng
  JOIN users
    ON users.id = mng.manager_id
WHERE  mng.week >= 1 AND mng.week <= 6  
GROUP BY manager_id
ORDER BY accumulated_score DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: out of the topic question, is there a way where i can view scores for each week, let's say mng.score for week1, mng.score for week2 .etc for each manager using only sql? i know it's possible to write some simple php script to achieve that, but always wonders if sql has the power.

Comment: actually if u are not grouping then mng.score shows the sore of manager between week 1 and week 6

Comment: @MohammedJoraid are u asking about GROUP BY manager_id with rollup??

Comment: I was talking about something else, guess it needs another question.However, The thing is, I need to access several tables, actually same table but older versions, and get the sum score from them for each manager. let's say we tables x_1, x_2, x_3, I need to get the  scores from the three tables and sum that score for each manager. 
let's say table x_1 has score = 1 for manager A. x_2 has score = 2, x_3 has score =3. So for manager A the sum score is 6. Now i need to get that sum for managers from A-Z. 
The question is, could i use only sql to achieve that, or it's a MUST to write some script?

Comment: yes you can do that it will be better if u post it as seprate question.with table structure..